# Webcam not found after re-installing Windows 7 (LiteOn Sonix SN9C230)

Tags: installation, drivers, webcam

On my Vostro 1310 laptop, I re-installed Windows 7, now I have trouble with my webcam.

I had a driver CD that came with my laptop, which I installed, but during setup it shows me error:

> error occurring through setup

When I download other versions, the installation process finishes and the machine will restart, but I don't see the webcam. I also tried USB webcams and nothing changed. I tried to go through the *Add Hardware* dialog too. It tells me "no driver found".

The driver name is: LiteOn Sonix SN9C230

How can I find out the problem?